# How to rollback after deploying to Google Cloud Run

Tags: rollback, google-cloud-run

I started playing with Google Cloud Run and, at least on the surface, it looks like a fantastic tool. One thing I can't figure out is how to do rollback efficiently.

I deploy my service via command line

```
gcloud beta run deploy my-service --image my-image
```

and ideally I'd like to have the option to rollback to the previous revision if I find a problem with my new deployment.

Is there a way to rollback or migrate the traffic to a specific revision?

Comment: I confirm, Cloud Run is awesome! I'm a fan (and Alpha tester). Great things are coming, stay tuned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coming feature on the managed platform! Be patient!

For now, simply deploy a new revision with the previous image. You can browse the image with the CLI of through the UI. Get the image with the digest and deploy it.

To list the revision use `gcloud beta run revisions list --filter <service name> --platform managed`

To get the image of your revision `gcloud beta run revisions describe <revision name> --platform managed --region <region> --format 'value(status.imageDigest)'`

Take care of env var if you change the between version (you can also see this on the GUI or with the CLI)

For listing the variable of a revision `gcloud beta run revisions describe <revision name> --platform managed --region <region> --format 'default(spec.containers)'`

For Cloud Run on GKE, you can update the route by using YAML. Start by extracting the route from CLoud Run
`gcloud beta run routes describe <service name> > route.yaml`

Change the revision pointed at the end of the description:

```
traffic:
  - percent: 100
    revisionName: <revision Name>
```

Then perform a `kubectl apply -f route.yaml`

Comment: I thought as much! Thanks for the suggested workaround, I'll try to be patient in the meanwhile.

Comment: I get this error when I apply `error: unable to recognize "route.yaml": no matches for kind "Route" in version "serving.knative.dev/v1alpha1`

Comment: Is this available yet? Would have saved us some time.

Comment: @adamshamsudeen [Route](https://knative.dev/v0.3-docs/reference/serving-api/#Route) is documented here and is a part of Knative serving 0.3. Check your cluster and your deployed component.

Comment: @LukePighetti, it's available on Cloud Run for Anthos (on GKE), and, thereby, on all K8S cluster compliant with Knative serving. On Cloud Run managed, it's not yet available.

Comment: It's coming but no date for now. Stay tune!